# Checking for possibility to place word horizontally or vertically in Crossword Game

Tags: c, comparison, puzzle, crossword

I have written the following code which takes in words from the user, sorts them from longest to shortest, and then checks to see if there is a possible place for the word to be put. What I am having trouble with is figuring out how to check whether the word can be placed horizontally or vertically. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void initialize_board(char board[][15]);
void get_user_info(char words[][16], int *numbofwords);
void sort_words(char words[][16], int numbofwords);
void display_solution_board(char board[][15]);
void place_words(char board[][15], char words[][16], int numbofwords);
int check_if_fits(char board[][15], char * word, int *j, int *n);


int main(){
    char words[20][16];
    char board[15][15];
    int numbofwords = 0;
    int i;
    //create a board of all pound symbols
    initialize_board(board);
    //get words for crossword from user
    get_user_info(words, &numbofwords);
    //sort words array to go from longest word to shortest
    sort_words(words,numbofwords);
    //places the words in appropriate places
    place_words(board,words,numbofwords);
    //displays the output of the board with answers
    display_solution_board(board);
}

void initialize_board(char board[][15]){
    int j,k;
    for(j = 0; j < 15; j++){
        for(k = 0; k < 15; k++){
            strcpy(&board[j][k],"#");
        }
    }
}

void get_user_info(char words[][16], int *numbofwords){
    char word[16];
    int i = 0;
    printf("Please enter up to 20 words of up to 15 characters in length.\n");
    printf("Use a period to end your input if you want less than 20 words.\n");
    scanf("%s", word);
    while(strcmp(word, ".") != 0){
        strcpy(words[i],word);
        i++;
        if(i == 20){
            break;
        }
        scanf("%s", word);
    }
    *numbofwords = i;

}

void sort_words(char words[][16], int numbofwords){
    int i, j;
    char temp[16];
    for(i = 0; i < numbofwords-1; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < numbofwords-i-1;j++){
            if(strlen(words[j]) < strlen(words[j+1])){
                strcpy(&temp[0],words[j]);
                strcpy(words[j],words[j+1]);
                strcpy(words[j+1],&temp[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}

void display_solution_board(char board[][15]){
    int j,k;
    for(j = 0; j < 15; j++){
        for(k = 0; k < 15; k++){
            printf("%c",board[j][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void place_words(char board[][15], char words[][16], int numbofwords){
int i,j,k,max;
int n,r = 0;

//sets the longest word in the middle of the grid
max = strlen(words[0]);
printf("max is %d\n",max);
printf("num words is %d\n",numbofwords);
strncpy(&board[7][(15-max)/2],words[0], strlen(words[0]));
//goes through all other words to find a place for them
for(i = 1; i < numbofwords; i++){
    if(check_if_fits(board,words[i],&j,&k) == 0 && check_vertical_placement(board,words[i],j,k) == 0){
        //printf("The word %s fits in col %d and row %d\n", words[i],k,j);
        for(k = k;k < strlen(words[i]);k++){
            board[j][k] = words[i][r];
            r++;
        }
    }else if(check_if_fits(board,words[i],&j,&k) == 0 && check_horizontal_placement(board,words[i],j,k) == 0){
        //printf("The word %s fits in col %d and row %d\n", words[i],k,j);
        for(j = j; j < strlen(words[i]); j++){
            board[j][k] = words[i][n];
            n++;
        }
    }else if(check_if_fits(board,words[i],&j,&k) == 1){
        printf("The word %s doesn't fit\n", words[i]);
    }
}
}

int check_if_fits(char board[][15], char * word, int *j, int *n){
    int k,t,h,g;
    for(t = 0; t < 15; t++){
        for(h = 0; h < 15; h++){
            for(k = 0; k < strlen(word); k++){
                if(board[t][h] == word[k]){
                    *j = t+1;
                    *n = h+1;
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int check_horizontal_placement(char board[][15],char * word, int j,int k){
    int i,val;
    for(i = k; i < strlen(word);i++){
        if(board[j][i] == '#' && board[j+1][i] == '#' && board[j-1][i] == '#') val = 0;
    }
    if(val == 0) return(0);
    else{return(1);}
}

int check_vertical_placement(char board[][15],char * word, int j,int k){
    int i,val;
    for(i = j; i < strlen(word);i++){
        if(board[i][k] == '#' && board[i][k+1] == '#' && board[i][k-1] == '#') val = 0;
    }
    if(val == 0) return(0);
    else{return(1);}
}
```

Comment: Your board is a 2d array of chars. Then don't do this: `strcpy(&board[j][k],"#")`. This will copy the hash mark, but it will also overwrite the next char in the array with the null terminator. You want `board[j][k] = '#')`. Note the single quotes; the hash in single quotes is just a single character.

Comment: @MOehm if it overwrites the next char then I would expect to have blank spaces on the board whenever I print it out, but that is not the case. I implemented your suggestion regardless because i see have it may cause error when checking the board

Comment: You overwrite the blank spaces immediately. Say you `strcpy` the hash string to `board[0[0]`. That places a `'#'` in `board[0][0]` and a `'\0'` (which you usually can't print) into `board[0][1]`. Next in your loop you initialise `board[0[[1]`, thereby overwriting the null character from the earlier strcpy. For the last cell on the board, you have an out-of-bounds memory access.

Comment: @MOehm Ok! I understand now! Do you have any suggestions as to how to check whether a word fits from above the middle row? I have updated my code to show a check from the first word in the middle horizontally or vertically but cannot come up with code which checks whether a word will fit from the top.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have any suggestions as to how to check whether a word fits
>   from above the middle row?

Replace in `place_words()` the body of your `for(i = 1; i < numbofwords; i++)` loop with

```
    switch (check_if_fits(board, words[i], &j, &k))
    {
    case -1:// vertical_placement
        //printf("The word %s fits in col %d and row %d\n", words[i],k,j);
        for (r = 0; r < strlen(words[i]); r++) board[j+r][k] = words[i][r];
        break;
    case 0: // horizontal_placement
        //printf("The word %s fits in col %d and row %d\n", words[i],k,j);
        for (n = 0; n < strlen(words[i]); n++) board[j][k+n] = words[i][n];
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("The word %s doesn't fit\n", words[i]);
    }
```

replace the lines `*j = t+1;`
                    `*n = h+1;` in `check_if_fits()` with checks for both placements:

```
                  if (check_vertical_placement(board, word, *j=t-k, *n=h)==0)
                    return -1;
                  if (check_horizontal_placement(board, word, *j=t, *n=h-k)==0)
```

and the check functions with

```
int check_horizontal_placement(char board[][15], char *word, int j, int k)
{
    int i;
    if (k < 0 || 15 < k+strlen(word)) return 1; // word outside board
    if (k && board[j][k-1] != '#') return 1;    // another word in front
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
        if (board[j][k+i] != '#' && board[j][k+i] != word[i]) return 1;
    if (k+i < 15 && board[j][k+i] != '#') return 1; // another word behind
    return 0;
}

int check_vertical_placement(char board[][15], char *word, int j, int k)
{
    int i;
    if (j < 0 || 15 < j+strlen(word)) return 1; // word outside board
    if (j && board[j-1][k] != '#') return 1;    // another word in front
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
        if (board[j+i][k] != '#' && board[j+i][k] != word[i]) return 1;
    if (j+i < 15 && board[j+i][k] != '#') return 1; // another word behind
    return 0;
}
```